# Obtaining T-S parameters with a mic

Tags: sound-design, speakers

For doing a bass-reflex box I need the Thielle-Small parameters.

I know I can get T-S with a mic recording a speaker, **but how**?

Can someone give me precise instructions about what I have to do?

I searched on the web (maybe with the incirrect words) how to do it, but nothing was found.

Any help is higly appreciated!

Comment: I think you're wrong about being able to determine Thiel Small parameters with a microphone. Normally they are available from the manufacturer of the driver in question. They are obtained by measuring and/or calculating the electrical and mechanical properties of the driver.

Comment: A bit late with this as I only saw it now. http://www.diyaudioandvideo.com/Tutorial/BuildMicrophoneForSpeakerTesting/ I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The assumptions of the question are incorrect.
Measuring a speaker to derive the Thiele-Small parameters does NOT require a microphone of any kind.  You can refer to a page like this to show how to measure the T/S parameters:

Measuring Thiele-Small Parameters V1.2
http://www.mh-audio.nl/downloads/read-measuring-tsp.pdf